# Winforms project deployment with SQL Server local database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I am currently developing a Winforms application as a college project, and I am currently stuck at deployment/publishing the project. I have tried to publish and run it in a different laptop, but I get an error whenever the application tries to establish a connection to SQL Server:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL Server is configure to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Here is the connection string I'm using:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=HRMS;Integrated Security=True
```

The application uses Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2.

The `.mdf` and `.ldf` files are included in the application files when publishing as data files and set SQL Server 2019 Express LocalDB as prerequisite. Also, I've installed SQL Server Express 2019 in the other laptop, while the one I use to work on the project uses Microsoft SQL Server 2019. The application works fine in the machine I'm using to develop it, but not in other devices. How do I properly deploy the application in other devices?

Comment: *I've installed SQL Server Express 2019* - your connection string uses **Local DB** - not SQL Server Express - have you installed **Local DB** as well? If not - that's your problem

Comment: Debug issue using SQL Server Management Studio. The login window will show Window Credentials which is the same as Integrated Security = True.  The login windows shows the Sever\Instance which must be the same as the Data Source in the connection string.  Using the SSMS check the log files with the explorer under Management and check when laptop failed.  See the group/user that was used to make connection and compare to successful with working machine.  Windows credentials requires the laptop to be in the same Windows Group as the Server and user must have an account on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

> "error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an
> automatic instance."

LocalDB is installed as a feature of SQL Server Express with Advanced Services or by downloading and running the standalone installer SqlLocalDB.msi.

To make sure it is actually installed on the target laptop run the "Installed SQL Server features discovery report" from the SQL Server Installation Centre.

[image]

If it is installed use the [SqlLocalDB utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) to troubleshoot the SQL LocalDb automatic instance.

Comment: Discovery report says LocalDB is installed, but the instance ID is just a "." and the instance is blank. I'm not familiar with troubleshooting the automatic instance with SqlLocalDB though, can you give some instructions on how to do that?

Comment: "sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB" will show you information about the LocalDB automatic instance. It will probably show with a state of "Stopped". Use "sqllocaldb start MSSQLLocalDB" to check if it can be succesfully started.